# Apex class DML query using bind variable

Tags: apex, bind-variable

The line "Integer days =" has an error, which I am trying to bind the Case record id to get "days" to be passed to the "createCase.Date_Due__c = date.today() + days; " Equipment__c is a lookup field on Case to Product2.  What is wrong here? Thanks for your help!

```
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {

public static void updateWorkOrders(List<Case> newCase, Map<Id,Case> oldMapCase) {
    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
    for (Case thisCase: newCase)         
    {
     Integer days = [Select Maintenance_Cycle__c from Product2 where id =:thisCase.Equipment__c];

        if (thisCase.Status=='Closed' && oldMapCase.get(thisCase.id).Status != 'Closed'){
            Case createCase = new Case();
            createCase.RecordTypeId = '0124W00000160QvQAI';
            createCase.subject = 'New Case Created';
            createCase.Equipment__c = thisCase.Equipment__c;
            createCase.Date_Due__c = date.today() + days; 
            caseList.add(createCase);
        }
    }
    insert caseList;
}
```

}

Comment: A SOQL query returns a `List<SObject>` in most cases, and that can't be converted to an `Integer` without a bit more work. What is the type of your `Maintenance_Cycle__c` field?

Comment: It is decimal and I've used valueOf() to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If maintenance cycle is an integer field then you can simply use it as.

`Integer days = [Select Maintenance_Cycle__c from Product2 where id =:thisCase.Equipment__c].Maintenance_Cycle__c;`

You may need to cast it to an integer to take the integer value if it is a decimal using `Integer valueOf()`.

The code assumes that query will always return something,  based on your data model, additional checks can be added if the query fails.

Comment: The new safe navigation operator makes this easier: `Integer days = [Select Maintenance_Cycle__c from Product2 where id =:thisCase.Equipment__c]?.Maintenance_Cycle__c?.intValue();`

Comment: @manjit thanks for your comment.  I got the code to work.  Just a bit more for my understanding - The SOQL returns the value of Maintenance_Cycle__c and then the dot notation follows it makes it as Maintenance_Cycle__c.Maintenance_Cycle__c?  What kind of traverse would this be? I understand a similar use of it i.e. account.industry can you elaborate?

Comment: The SOQL will return the complete record of Product 2 and from that we are taking out the value of maintenance cycle. In Salesforce a SOQL query either return a record, a list of records or an integer (if you run a count) Please review the SOQL reference documentation